# visual studios 2012 after opening one file, I cant find the previous file I had open in the Document Well

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Anyone know how to make the document well act like vs2010?  Every time I open a file in the solution I lose the previous file unless I pin it.  I want it to act like a stack.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you double click a file you have the same behavior as in VS10. You can deactivate the preview function in solution explorer (i believe one of the right buttons - unfortunately I have no VS12 by the hand at the moment, so I can tell the exact position).

Comment: also I had to turn off sorting by project and alphabetically in Options->productivity power tools->custom document well

Comment: Would be nice if you can mark the question as answered :-) Thanks.